# Jolla: Can third party applications launch other applications in jolla?

Tags: android, security, privacy

I was thinking if Android applications or harbour applications can launch other application like Android/harbour application launching native applications OR other android or harbour applications? because this could be security risk if user permissions are not taken for the same or user permissions of launched application are used by applications launching these apps.

Answer (score 0):

SailfishOS allows an QML application to ask the launcher to launch other application via Qt.openUrlExternally(). You can launch a given file/protocol handling app, or a given app via pointing its .desktop file.

The new application is launched by the launcher and there is no possibility for remoting a launched app, so unless the launched app is not dangerous in itself, you cannot force it to do something user would not do. But who would install & run "dangerous" app anyway? And you cannot sideload an random app, as the interfaces required to do so are not allowed in Harbor.

Also, you cannot abuse user permissions, as there is only one 'nemo' user running all user level apps and there is no direct root access. (You can enable developer mode and gain root access via devel-su, but that requires knowing devel mode password.)

Android layer (Alien Dalvik) has all the usual Android protection mechanisms in place.